# AOSP: How to initialize the VehicleProperty::AUDIO_VOLUME property (.initialValues in the DefaultConfig.h) in vehicl hal?

Tags: android, android-source, android-8.0-oreo, hal

Trying to add AUDIO_VOLUME property to the demo vehicle hal code present in `/hardware/interfaces/automotive/vehicle/2.0/default/impl/vhal_v2_0/`

File name: DefaultConfig.h
tried adding like below, but it is crashing.

```
    {.config =
        {
            .prop = toInt(VehicleProperty::AUDIO_VOLUME),
            .access = VehiclePropertyAccess::READ_WRITE,
            .changeMode = VehiclePropertyChangeMode::ON_CHANGE,
            .configArray = { toInt(VehicleAudioContextFlag::MUSIC_FLAG), toInt(VehicleAudioVolumeCapabilityFlag::MASTER_VOLUME_ONLY),0,0,100 },
        },
        .initialValue = {.int32Values = { toInt(VehicleAudioContextFlag::MUSIC_FLAG), 80, toInt(VehicleAudioVolumeState::STATE_OK)  } }
    },
```

AUDIO_VOLUME property as defined in

```
/hardware/interfaces/automotive/vehicle/2.0/types.hal
     * @change_mode VehiclePropertyChangeMode:ON_CHANGE
     * @access VehiclePropertyAccess:READ_WRITE
     * @config_flags all audio contexts supported.
     */
    AUDIO_VOLUME = (
        0x0901
        | VehiclePropertyGroup:SYSTEM
        | VehiclePropertyType:INT32_VEC
        | VehicleArea:GLOBAL),
```

reference OSP code available in http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/

Answer (score 0):

Use hidl_vec to pack the initial value.

Example:

```
{.config =
        {
            .prop = toInt(VehicleProperty::AUDIO_VOLUME),
            .access = VehiclePropertyAccess::READ_WRITE,
            .changeMode = VehiclePropertyChangeMode::ON_CHANGE,
            .configArray = { toInt(VehicleAudioContextFlag::MUSIC_FLAG), toInt(VehicleAudioVolumeCapabilityFlag::MASTER_VOLUME_ONLY),0,0,100 },
        },
        .initialValue = {.int32Values = hidl_vec<int32_t> {toInt(VehicleAudioContextFlag::MUSIC_FLAG), 80, toInt(VehicleAudioVolumeState::STATE_OK) }}
    },
```

As this property expects an INT32_VEC value.

Comment: What is `hidl_vec` ?